# How to get Image Account of user currently logged on Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Searching on the web I found this code UWP, to get the image but I'm not be able to include namespace Windows.Storage in WPF. I tried to include all possible references but doesn't work. I would have a solution WPF to include Windows.Storage(if possible) or simply another way to implement code to get image

```
StorageFile image = UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(AccountPictureKind.SmallImage) as StorageFile;
        if (image != null)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("SmallImage path = " + image.Path, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Small Account Picture is not available", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            mediaPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            smallImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            largeImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

}

Comment: This code snippet seems to apply to UWP.

Comment: I think they might be stored in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures`

Comment: @itsme86 thank you, but in the folder i can find all photos used for account. I should get photo currently used.

Comment: @mm8 i have just seen that Windows.Storage is for UWP. you're right. I should find a way to get Image from WPF project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Windows.​System.​User​Profile` namespace is for [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp) app development and does not apply to WPF.

You may be able to use it if you package (convert) your app to UWP: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#apis-supported-in-both-converted-apps-and-desktop-applications. Note that the `UserInformation` class is not supported on Windows 10 or later. Instead, you should use the [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.user) class.

In a .NET application, you could try to search the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Account Pictures` folder for the latest modified file:

[How to find the most recent file in a directory using .NET, and without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that the simplier solution is find in the folder the latest modified file

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677719/how-can-i-extract-the-current-users-account-picture) if you take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776892(VS.85).aspx)

As long as you have the currently logged in username, you should be able to access it. This is the case for Win OS 7 at least, I don't know which OS you're working with.